# file protocol link not responding

Tags: iis, hyperlink, protocol

We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 hosting IIS8. One of the websites is a basic html page with links on it (the server hosts other internal sites so they just made this basic one since IIS was already up and running).
We also have a SharePoint WFE on another server. On SharePoint we put a link to a *shortcut* (they pass parameters via target in properties. Don't know why it's done this way, but I don't see them changing their ways).
For testing purposes I also made a share on my computer, created a simple html page with an  link pointing to the same shortcut.
Both SharePoint and my html page links work fine, but when we click the link on the server nothing happens. The server hosted page has http protocol links on it also and they work as intended, it's only file:/// protocols that refuse to do anything.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I've tried IE 11, Chrome, and Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply changing the authentication from Anon to Windows Auth resolved the problem.